# Uploading to Sharepoint Without Scanning

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, upload, paperless

I'm pretty new to using sharepoint and I know it has a lot of potential but I cannot seem to find an answer.

Right now at my work we upload to sharepoint by printing items sticking a bar code on it and sending it to the specific email through the printer. This causes us to use a lot of paper which we don't necessarily need to use.

I'm wondering if there would be a way to instead create a PDF out of some document like an invoice. Attach the bar code as a cover sheet to that PDF, upload that to something like a drive on the network which then uploads the individual PDF's the sharepoint allowing us to skip the scanning process.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, we don't have a expert in share point anymore and neither does my school.

Comment: sharepoint allows users to upload files to document libraries, or attach file to listitems (child of list). Of course there are also APIs to do this programatically.

Comment: additional information: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-a-document-library-3b5976dd-65cf-4c9e-bf5a-713c10ca2872

Comment: Appreciated, looks like I'll need a little information from my IT department on what actually happens in the background.